# ASP.NET MVC user customizable template

Tags: html, json, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, templates

I have a query that returns around 70 fields from the DB, which represents a message. As there are around 10 messages the result has to be displayed in 10 different ways. For example if the SQL contains A, B, C, D, E, F, G, and H; then Message 1 can contain - A, D, and G. Message 2 can contain - A, F, and E. Message 3 can contain B, F, and H.

My initial idea was to have several classes and map the main object to the smaller ones. But this was not accepted as the requirement is that the message format has to be easily modified (without redeploying).

My other idea was to use some HTML editor and have several templates for the messages and pass this as a Razor template, but this was not accepted as the editor has to be as simple as including and excluding fields.

I though about using Handlebar, but I guess it will be rejected as well. Probably store the different message formats in MongoDB.  How do you combine the templates with the values then?

Comment: I handle this type of issues by having a main class including 70 fields and then casting them to different interfaces for limited numbers of fields.

Comment: Thanks! This is a good solution. But I was looking more for a library like DataTables.
Here you can easily set the dataset and columns dinamically:

var dataSet = [
    [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "$320,800" ],

];
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );